# placement new with different types in preallocated memory - how to guarantee alignment?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to build a class that can be used as some sort of *shared pointer*. For performance reasons I'd like to implement a factory function that allocates the memory for the object and a `unsigned int` reference counter in a single step:

```
template<typename T> class SharedPointer {

  uint8_t* buffer;
  T* obj;
  unsigned int* counter;

  template<typename Args...> static SharedPointer make(Args&&... args) {
    SharedPointer p;
    p.buffer = new uint8_t[sizeof(T) + sizeof(unsigned int)];
    p.obj = new (p.buffer) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    p.counter = new (p.buffer + sizeof(T)) unsigned int(1);
    return p;
  }

}
```

And later, when the shared object is about to be deleted:

```
~SharedPointer() {
  *counter--;
  if (*counter == 0) {
    obj->~T();
    delete[] buffer;
  }
}
```

The question is: is it necessary to set the correct memory alignment for the allocated buffer and how can this be achieved? I know the keyword `alignas`, but I don't know how it should be integrated here.

**Update:**
As pointed out in the comments, std::aligned_storage can be used. Will this be a possible solution then:

```
template<typename T> class SharedPointer {

  struct Storage {
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> obj;
    unsigned int counter;
  };

  Storage* buffer;
  T* obj;
  unsigned int* counter;

  template<typename Args...> static SharedPointer make(Args&&... args) {
    SharedPointer p;
    p.buffer = new Storage();
    p.obj = new (p.buffer) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    p.counter = new (p.buffer + sizeof(T)) unsigned int(1);
    return p;
  }

  ~SharedPointer() {
    *counter--;
    if (*counter == 0) {
      obj->~T();
      delete buffer;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You can use [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage)

Comment: Define `struct Storage { unsigned int counter; std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alighof(T)> storage; }` and allocate memory for that.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what are your arguments against just using `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @mutex36: "Curiosity" can also be the answer to this question :)
I'm just trying things out to learn

Comment: there might be padding in between `obj` and `counter` so you need to used [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) instead of `sizeof(T)` when finding the address of `counter`